# Setting invalid data to missing data in Spark DataFrames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions, missing-data

Let x be the dataframe of two columns of strings defined as (in Scala)

```
case class Pair(X: String, Y: String)

val x = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
   Pair("u1", "1"), 
   Pair("u2", "wrong value"), 
   Pair("u3", "5"), 
   Pair("u4", "2")
))
```

I want to clean this dataframe such that each value of the second column is

1. casted to Int if possible
2. replace by null, Na or any symbol meaning "missing value" (not NaN, which is different)

I was thinking of using udf functions

```
val stringToInt = udf[Int, String](x => try {
     x.toInt
   } catch {
     case e: Exception => null
   })

x.withColumn("Y", stringToInt(x("Y")))
```

... but null is not a String, and the compiler refuse it. Please, what is the solution for it? A completely different approach would be fine too as long as I can clean my dataframe

Comment: Note that val x = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(Pair("u1", "a1"), Pair("u1", "a2"), Pair("u2", "a1"), Pair("u2", null))) return a dataframe of two columns of strings with one null value, and we can use standard tools like x.na.drop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually in this particular case there is no need for an UDF. Instead you can safely use `Column.cast` method:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType
val clean = x.withColumn("Y", $"Y".cast(IntegerType)) // or .cast("integer")

clean.where($"Y".isNotNull).show
// +---+---+
// |  X|  Y|
// +---+---+
// | u1|  1|
// | u3|  5|
// | u4|  2|
// +---+---+

clean.where($"Y".isNull).show
// +---+----+
// |  X|   Y|
// +---+----+
// | u2|null|
// +---+----+
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `null`, use `Option[Int]`:

```
val pairs = Seq(
   Pair("u1", "1"), 
   Pair("u2", "wrong value"), 
   Pair("u3", "5"), 
   Pair("u4", "2")
)

def toInt(s: String): Option[Int] = try { Some(s.toInt) } catch { case NumberFormatException => None }

val stringToInt = udf[Int, Option[Int]](toInt _)
```

Then you can do

```
val x = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pairs)
x.withColumn("Y", stringToInt(x("Y")))
```

Comment: Please, review my modifs

Comment: Why not simply `Try(s.toInt).toOption`?

Comment: @zero323 No real reason, that's also appropriate. It might generate different bytecode though

Comment: It would, but I believe it would be more idiomatic here not to mention shorter :) Anyway +1.

Comment: @zero323 It is semantically different from what I've listed though, in that it catches any exception (may be better or worse), and it almost certainly boxes the value more than the primitive try/catch (may or may not be important)

Comment: Thats true, although it is correct if you accept SQL semantics.